# SSRS 2016 - Report server Web Services - Dataset issue

Tags: web-services, timeout, dataset, ssrs-2016

I’m trying to run a Dataset to build a KPI on SSRS 2016 Enterprise addition but, it give me the hereunder message although it run fine on the Report Builder:

[An Error has occurred.
The data set could not be processed .
There was a problem getting data from the Report server Web Services.]

I already changed the Dataset Timeout to Zero and the Database Query Time out to Zero on the RsReportServer.config

When I limit the Dataset to one row (a shorter query) it run fine which, mean the issue could be in the Web service or session timeout.

Comment: Set the timeout in Datasource

Answer (score 0):

Setting Time-out Values for Report and Shared Dataset Processing (SSRS)

- You can Reporting Services specify time-out values to set limits on
  how system resources are used. Report server supports two time-out
  values: An embedded dataset query time-out value is the number of
  seconds that the report server waits for a response from the
  database. This value is defined in a report.
- A shared dataset query time-out value is the number of seconds that
  the report server waits for a response from the database. This value
  is part of the shared dataset definition and can be changed when you
  manage the shared dataset on the report server.
- A report execution time-out value is the maximum number of seconds
  that report processing can continue before it is stopped. This value
  is defined at the system level. You can vary this setting for
  individual reports.

Most time-out errors occur during query
   processing. If you are encountering time-out errors, try increasing
   the query time-out value. Make sure to adjust the report execution
   time-out value so that it is larger than the query time-out. The time
   period should be sufficient to complete both query and report
   processing.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-server/setting-time-out-values-for-report-and-shared-dataset-processing-ssrs

Comment: Thank you Kishore for your reply.

Comment: Thank you Kishore for your reply. I already set the Shared Dataset timeout to Zero and the Database Query Time out to Zero on the [RsReportServer.config] but I revive the error after 120 sec each time I try to preview the data on the Portal or use the Dataset in building a KPI in the Portal although, the Shared Dataset run fine in the Report Builder. I think the issue could be related to Web Services or related component ... any suggestion.

Comment: Have you tried with Report timeout  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.services.protocols.webclientprotocol.timeout.aspx